# On using "conscious"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

When I want to use `conscious` and `unconscious` in specific context, for example, `security conscious users`, which is correct:

`security-conscious users` (with dash), or `security conscious users` (without dash). the same question for `unconscious`, is it:
`security-unconscious users` (with dash), or `security unconscious users` (without dash).

Comment: conscious and unconscious are not related in your usage of conscious. unconscious is psychology or psychoanalytical....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to hyphenate compound adjectives like security-conscious. It prevents it being read as "users who are conscious and security".

However "security-unconscious" sounds very odd. It isn't the opposite of "security-conscious"  Instead talk about "less security-conscious users" or "users who are not security-conscious".

Comment: What about `non-security-conscious`?

Comment: perhaps, but long compound adjectives get confusing when put in front of the noun, so it is better to move them to a relative clause "people who are less security-conscious". "Less" is also better then "non-" because nobody is completely unaware of security.